# Float Left without going through another DIV

Tags: html, css, css-float

I am trying to add a sidebar to my website.
I've been trying to create a `div` that will function as the menu, with the following code:

```
      <div style="">
          <div style="display:inline;width:70%;">
                hey
           </div>
           <div style="float:left;width:20%;">
               <div style="background-color:#F2F2F2;font-weight:bold;padding:7px;">Title</div>
               text<br /><br />f
           </div>
       </div>
```

Then, I got the following results:

[image]

The sidebar goes through another `div`, and does not function as an individual `div`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to clear your float to resolve this issue.

**For Instance, in your case,**

```
<div style="clear:left;">&nbsp;</div>
```